# How to solve the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android while implement Sliding menu?

Tags: android

I get the following error's while I am implementing [jeremyfeinstein Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in my Android Application,please kindly help me how to solve this issues.

```
07-12 10:29:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2169): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-117

07-12 10:29:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2169): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.rss.on2nyt.FragmentChangeActivity

07-12 10:29:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(2169): at com.rss.on2nyt.Splash$IntentLauncher.run(Splash.java:99)
```

Comment: Looks like that class definition isn't being found.  It's on line 99 of Splash.java.  Have you researched other NoClassDefFoundErrors to see the common causes?  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java .  Also, make sure you've added your library to the class path.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this way:
copy the sliding menu's android-support-v4.jar form libs to you project and clean you project.